# FileStream from the System.IO namespace instead of Get-Content -Tail

Tags: powershell

I want to use a FileStream from the System.IO namespace instead of Get-Content cmd-let. How can I do that ?

thanks,

```
$fromaddress = "filemon@contoso.com"
$emailto = "IT@contoso.com"
$SMTPSERVER = "xx.xx.xx.xx"
$global:FileChanged = $false 
$folder = "C:\temp" 
$filter = "log.log" 
$watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder,$filter -Property @{ IncludeSubdirectories = $false EnableRaisingEvents = $true }
Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher "Changed" -Action {$global:FileChanged = $true} > $null

while ($true)
{ 
    while ($global:FileChanged -eq $false){ 
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 
    }

    if($(Get-Content -Tail 1 -Path $folder\$filter).Contains("Finished."))
    {
        Send-mailmessage -from $fromaddress -to $emailto -subject "Log changed" -smtpServer $SMTPSERVER -Encoding UTF8 -Priority High
    }

    # reset and go again
    $global:FileChanged = $false
}
```

EDIT 1:

```
$fromaddress = "filemon@contoso.com"
$emailto = "IT@contoso.com"
$SMTPSERVER = "xx.xx.xx.xx"
$global:FileChanged = $false 
$folder = "C:\tmp" 
$filter = "log.log" 
$watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder,$filter -Property @{ IncludeSubdirectories = $false ; EnableRaisingEvents = $true }
Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher "Changed" -Action {$global:FileChanged = $true} > $null

function Read-LastLine ([string]$Path) {
    # construct a StreamReader object
    $reader   = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($path)
    $lastLine = ''
    while($null -ne ($line = $reader.ReadLine())) {
        $lastLine = $line
    }

    # clean-up the StreamReader
    $reader.Dispose()

    # return the last line of the file
    $lastLine
}

while ($true)
{ 
    while ($global:FileChanged -eq $false){ 
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 
    }
    
    $logFile = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath

    if ((Read-LastLine -Path $logFile) -match "Finished.")
    {
       write-host "mail sending"
        Send-mailmessage -from $fromaddress -to $emailto -subject "Log changed" -smtpServer $SMTPSERVER -Encoding UTF8 -Priority High
    }

    # reset and go again
    $global:FileChanged = $false
}
```

Message:

```
MethodInvocationException: C:\monfile.ps1:15
Line |
  15 |      $reader   = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($path)
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "The value cannot be an empty string. (Parameter 'path')"
InvalidOperation: C:\monfile.ps1:17
Line |
  17 |      while($null -ne ($line = $reader.ReadLine())) {
     |                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
InvalidOperation: C:\monfile.ps1:22
Line |
  22 |      $reader.Dispose()
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
```

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this would be faster than using `Get-Content -Tail 1`, but you could create a helper function that uses a [StreamReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader) to return the last line in the file.

**Edit**

Your code does not really respond to the event when it happens, but seems to rely on a global variable called `FileChanged` which you test inside a while loop.

The magic with a FileSystemWatcher is that you can just sit back and relax until the chosen event fires, in your case if something has changed in the `log.log` file.
Only when such an event occurs, the scripblock defined in the `Action` parameter is executed, so here's a rewrite of your code using a helper function to read the last line of the log file.

(since my earliear answer, I have changed that function to only retrieve the last line that is not empty or whitespace only)

```
function Read-LastLine {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [Alias('FullName')]
        [string]$Path
    )
    # construct a StreamReader object
    $reader   = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($path)
    $lastLine = [string]::Empty
    while($null -ne ($line = $reader.ReadLine())) {
        # do not store this line if it is empty or whitespace-only
        if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($line)) {
            $lastLine = $line
        }
    }

    # clean-up the StreamReader
    $reader.Dispose()

    # return the last line of the file
    $lastLine
}

# create a splatting Hashtable for the Send-MailMessage cmdlet
$mailParams = @{
    From       = "filemon@contoso.com"
    To         = "IT@contoso.com"
    SmtpServer = "xx.xx.xx.xx"
    Subject    = "Log changed"
    Encoding   = 'UTF8'
    Priority   = 'High'
}

# define parameters for the FileSystemWatcher
$folder = 'C:\tmp'
$filter = 'log.log'

# to prevent the FileSystemWatcher to fire events twice, keep track of the last time
$LastEventTime = (Get-Date)

# define the Action scriptblock for the FileSystemWatcher
# this code which will be executed every time a file change is detected
$action = {
    # try to detect if this event fired twice
    if (($Event.TimeGenerated.Ticks - $script:LastEventTime.Ticks) -gt 100000) {
        $logFile = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
        if ((Read-LastLine -Path $logFile) -match "Finished") {
            $script:LastEventTime = $Event.TimeGenerated
            Write-Host "mail sending"
            Send-mailmessage @mailParams
        }
    }
}

# create the FileSystemWatcher and register the event
$watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
    IncludeSubdirectories = $false
    EnableRaisingEvents   = $true
    NotifyFilter          = [IO.NotifyFilters]::LastWrite
}
Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher -EventName 'Changed' -SourceIdentifier 'LogChanged' -Action $action
```

When you no longer need to watch the file, unregister the event and dispose of the watcher

```
Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier 'LogChanged'
$watcher.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
$SourceStream = [System.IO.FileStream]::new('c:\temp\test.txt',[System.IO.FileMode]::Open);
for($pos = $SourceStream.Length - 1; $pos -ge 0; $pos--)
{
   $SourceStream.Position = $pos
   $b = $SourceStream.ReadByte()
   if(($b -eq 0x0A) -or ($b -eq 0x0D)) { break;}
}
$length = $SourceStream.Length - $pos
$buffer = New-Object byte[]($length)
$SourceStream.Read([byte[]]$buffer, 0, $length)
$tail = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($buffer, 0, $length)
Write-Host $tail
```

Comment: thanks but , How do I integrate your script to my script?

Comment: Use $buffer.   You may need to convert to string using : $str = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($buffer)

Comment: But this would return the entire content of the file (just like Get-Content -Raw) whereas the OP wants only the last line.

Comment: @Theo : You are making an assumption that OP want ONLY.  OP question is to use FileStream and that is what I answered.  With OP stream you can set position and then read just the end.  OP apparently is familiar with Net Library.

Comment: No assumption. The OP's code clearly states `Get-Content -Tail 1` and also the title gives you a hint.

Comment: I updated code to get lastline

Answer (score 0):

There is one real problem with reading the last line of a log file that is being written to by software that you didn't create - How do you know it is only adding one line, or log entry, at a time? What you really need is something that keeps track of the log file and reads only new content as it is added.  My solution to this is to create a LogFileReader class.

In a test script I created, I added to the top of the script the following lines taken, as is, from the question:

```
$fromaddress = "filemon@contoso.com"
$emailto = "IT@contoso.com"
$SMTPSERVER = "xx.xx.xx.xx"
$global:FileChanged = $false 
$folder = "C:\tmp" 
$filter = "log.log" 
$watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder,$filter -Property @{ IncludeSubdirectories = $false ; EnableRaisingEvents = $true }
Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher "Changed" -Action {$global:FileChanged = $true} > $null
```

Then added this experimental LogFileReader class.  I created this class sometime in the last few weeks to address this issue.  So far it works well and I'm not seeing it throw errors or have problems.  But again, it is experimental and not thoroughly tested.

For this class:

1. Create an instance with the full path of the file, and optionally you can add the encoding.  If no encoding is provided, then UTF8 is the default.
2. If you want to read the full file prior to reading new lines, then make a call to either `ReadLines()` or `ReadText()`, else, make a call to `GoToEnd()` to skip the current content of the file.
3. `ReadLines()` returns an array of strings.  If you want to get each newly added line one at time, use this.
4. `ReadText()` returns a single string.  If you want all the newly added content as a single string, use this.
5. When done, use `Dispose()` to release the StreamReader.  **Edit:** Replaced the old `Dispose()` method with a new one that retrieves the FileStream from StreamReader's BaseStream property, disposes of the StreamReader, and then disposes of the FileStream.
6. If for some reason, after several reads, you want to read the file from the beginning, call `GoToStart()` and then the next read will get the entire file's content.
7. The class maintains a pointer that points to the end the last read, and with each call to `ReadLines()`, the pointer is moved forward the the end of the current read.  `ReadText()' calls` ReadLines()`, so the pointer is also advanced with each call to` ReadText()`.

```
class LogFileReader: IDisposable {
    [string]$_logFile
    [int]$_position
    [IO.StreamReader]$_streamReader
    hidden [void]Initialize([string]$logFile, [Text.Encoding]$encoding) {
        $this._logFile = $logFile
        $this._position = 0
        $this._streamReader = if ([IO.File]::Exists($this._logFile)) {
            [IO.StreamReader]::new([IO.FileStream]::new( $logFile, [IO.FileMode]::Open, [IO.FileAccess]::Read, [IO.FileShare]::ReadWrite), $encoding)
        } else {$null}
    }
    LogFileReader([string]$logFile) { $this.Initialize($logFile, [Text.Encoding]::UTF8) }
    LogFileReader([string]$logFile, [Text.Encoding]$encoding) { $this.Initialize($logFile, $encoding) }
    [void]GoToStart() { $this._position = 0 }
    [void]GoToEnd() { if($this._streamReader){$this._position = $this._streamReader.BaseStream.Length} }
    [string[]]ReadLines() {
        $Lines = @()
        if($this._streamReader) {
            $BaseLength = $this._streamReader.BaseStream.Length
            if ( $this._position -ne $BaseLength ) {
                if($this._position -gt $BaseLength ) { $this.GotoStart() }
                $null = $this._streamReader.BaseStream.Seek($this._position, [IO.SeekOrigin]::Begin)
                while ($null -ne ($Line = $this._streamReader.ReadLine())) {if($Line){$Lines += $Line}}
                $this._position = $this._streamReader.BaseStream.Position
            }
        }
        return $Lines
    }
    [string]ReadText() {
        $Return = ''
        $this.ReadLines() | ForEach-Object {$Return += "$_$([System.Environment]::NewLine)"}
        return $Return
    }
    [void]Dispose() {
        try{
            [IO.FileStream]$FileStream = $this._streamReader.BaseStream
            $this._streamReader.Dispose()
            $FileStream.Dispose()
        }
        finally{}
    }
}
```

The following test code was added to the end of the script.  **EDIT:** It now has commented out code that allows catching Ctrl+C and [Gracefully stopping in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1789948/4190564). Apparently, `[console]::TreatControlCAsInput` isn't available in all situation, even though the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.treatcontrolcasinput?view=netframework-4.6.2) don't appear to give enough info to explain when it isn't.  It also includes 3 version of the reading of the new content.  A `foreach {}` version with `if` for catching "Finished." line, and 2 commented out versions to give example uses.

The `Send-mailmessage` line is commented out, and an extra `Write-Host "[$Line]"` added for testing purposes.

```
$LogFileReader = [LogFileReader]::new("$folder\$filter", [Text.Encoding]::UTF8)
$LogFileReader.GoToEnd()

#[console]::TreatControlCAsInput = $true
:TrappedForever while ($true) {
    while ($global:FileChanged -eq $false){
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
        #if ($Host.UI.RawUI.KeyAvailable -and (3 -eq [int]$Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("AllowCtrlC,IncludeKeyUp,NoEcho").Character)) {break TrappedForever}
    }
    foreach ($Line in $LogFileReader.ReadLines()) {
        Write-Host "[$Line]"
        if ($Line -match "Finished.") {
            write-host "mail sending"
            #Send-mailmessage -from $fromaddress -to $emailto -subject "Log changed" -smtpServer $SMTPSERVER -Encoding UTF8 -Priority High
        }
    }
    #$LogFileReader.ReadLines() | ForEach-Object {Write-Host "[$_]"}
    #Write-Host ($LogFileReader.ReadText()) -NoNewline

    # reset and go again
    $global:FileChanged = $false
}
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $false
$watcher.Dispose()
$LogFileReader.Dispose()
Write-Host "All Done!"
```

Comment: thanks man! btw, how do we use your class in my script ? Also , I will catch specific keyword such as `success:$true`.  Finally , I will send the mail via send-mailmessage cmd-let. could you please share full script ?

Comment: Also , I won't use `for ($i = 0; $i -lt 3; $i++)``. I need to use indefinitely loop whilte(true).

Comment: The `for ($i = 0; $i -lt 3; $i++)` is for testing, not for final use.  I don't have the time at the moment, but maybe this afternoon I'll have the time and can create an example closer to your use.  Basically, it would involve appending each line either by `+=` to an array, or using stringbuilder, and then using it's content when "Finished" is matched.

Comment: @Arbelac, when I last replied, I thought you were wanting to send the newly added content of the log file in the body of the email.  But it looks like you are just wanting to know when the "Finished." line has newly appeared.  The new code replaces the questionable Dispose() with a new version that should correctly do the job, it now stays in the While loop, but watches for Ctrl+C (not sure how reliable this works), and gives an example use that should be closer to what you are doing.

Comment: I have an issue.  could you please help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75906202/the-lastlogontimestamp-and-lastlogon-attribute-for-more-real-time-logon-tracki

Answer (score 0):

### No `IO.FileSystemWatcher` Version:

While looking up references for my previous answer, I discovered that the LogFileReader class I created was based on C# code, [How to read a log file which is hourly updated in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32474950/4190564), that is remarkably similar to the code presented in the original code.

This LogFileWatcher class is similar to the previous LogFileReader class, but stripped down to the basics, and with a `Dirty()` method that indicates when more lines are available:

```
class LogFileWatcher: IDisposable {
    [IO.StreamReader]$_streamReader
    [int]$_position
    hidden [void]Initialize([string]$logFile, [Text.Encoding]$encoding) {
        $this._position = 0
        $this._streamReader = if ([IO.File]::Exists($logFile)) {
            [IO.StreamReader]::new([IO.FileStream]::new( $logFile, [IO.FileMode]::Open, [IO.FileAccess]::Read, [IO.FileShare]::ReadWrite), $encoding)
        } else {$null}
    }
    LogFileWatcher([string]$logFile) { $this.Initialize($logFile, [Text.Encoding]::UTF8) }
    LogFileWatcher([string]$logFile, [Text.Encoding]$encoding) { $this.Initialize($logFile, $encoding) }
    [void]GoToEnd() { if($this._streamReader){$this._position = $this._streamReader.BaseStream.Length} }
    [bool]Dirty() {
        return $this._position -ne $this._streamReader.BaseStream.Length
    }
    [string[]]ReadLines() {
        $Lines = @()
        if($this._streamReader -and $this.Dirty()) {
            $null = $this._streamReader.BaseStream.Seek($this._position, [IO.SeekOrigin]::Begin)
            while ($null -ne ($Line = $this._streamReader.ReadLine())) {if($Line){$Lines += $Line}}
            $this._position = $this._streamReader.BaseStream.Position
        }
        return $Lines
    }
    [void]Dispose() {
        try{
            [IO.FileStream]$FileStream = $this._streamReader.BaseStream
            $this._streamReader.Dispose()
            $FileStream.Dispose()
        }
        finally{}
    }
}
```

Example use, a hybrid of the C# code, and code in previous answer:

```
$fromaddress = "filemon@contoso.com"
$emailto = "IT@contoso.com"
$SMTPSERVER = "xx.xx.xx.xx"
$folder = "C:\tmp"
$filter = "log.log"

$LogFileWatcher = [LogFileWatcher]::new("$folder\$filter", [Text.Encoding]::UTF8)
$LogFileWatcher.GoToEnd()

while ($true) {
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
    if($LogFileWatcher.Dirty) {
        foreach ($Line in $LogFileWatcher.ReadLines()) {
            if ($Line -match "Finished.") {
                write-host "mail sending"
                Send-mailmessage -from $fromaddress -to $emailto -subject "Log changed" -smtpServer $SMTPSERVER -Encoding UTF8 -Priority High
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, if memory serves me correctly, it was [What's the least invasive way to read a locked file in C# (perhaps in unsafe mode)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25768988/4190564) that gave me the clues needed to eventually find the above link with code I used.

Comment: thanks , I have been using .net framework 4.6.2 and Powershell 5.1 on 2016 OS. I am getting `Exception setting "TreatControlCAsInput": "The handle is invalid.`

Comment: @Arbelac, updated the code.  Sorry to hear that the part exiting on Ctrl+C is failing.  The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.treatcontrolcasinput?view=netframework-4.6.2#applies-to) mention nothing that I can tell that explains why you would have a that problem.  But in working on this, I discovered that the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.dispose?view=netframework-4.6.2#system-io-streamreader-dispose(system-boolean)) for StreamReader says `Dispose(Boolean)` should work, but didn't for me.

Comment: thanks man! I have noticed something. if I use ANSI or UTF-8 as encoding type then it works. (it catching a string such as `Finished.`).  if I use unicode as encoding type then it NOT works.  (it not catching a string such as `Finished.`).

Comment: @Arbelac, ANSI and UTF8 are identical for most basic characters.  They become different when you start getting into special unicode characters that only UTF8 can handle, or I believe the upper 128 characters of ANSI that UTF8 would probably mistake for unicode.

Comment: @Arbelac, UTF8 is a type of unicode encoding where the most basic characters are a single byte in size, and I believe other characters are 2 bytes (possibly even longer).  The other unicode encoding may be two bytes in size for all characters. The whole thing is a complex mess and it would be nice if we only had one or two types of encoding to worry about.